# Why can't pytest find the 'client' fixture when testing a Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have a simple flask app, i want to test it using pytest.

my `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app(self):
    app = create_app(TestingConfig)

    return app
```

my `test_view.py`:

```
class TestMainView:

def test_ping(self, client):
    res = client.get(url_for('main.index'))
    assert res.status_code == 200
```

when i run the test's using `pytest` it's throwing an error saying:

```
fixture 'client' not found
>       available fixtures: app, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

i have another testing file where i test default configs and it passes:

```
class TestTestingClass(object):
app = create_app(TestingConfig)

def test_app_is_test(self):
    ''' test the test enviroment is set okay and works'''
    assert self.app.config['SECRET_KEY'] == 'something hard'
    assert self.app.config['DEBUG'] == True
    assert self.app.config['TESTING'] == True
    assert current_app is not None
    assert self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] == 'sqlite:////tmp/testing.db'
```

**edit**:
i was able to pass an empty test by changing to:

`conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app(TestingConfig)

    return app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

and my test file to:

```
def test_index(client):
   assert True
```

but, still i can't pass the `test_index` if it was:

```
def test_index(client):
   assert client.get(url_for('main.index')).status_code == 200
```

but this time, I'm getting an error stating that says:

```
RuntimeError: Attempted to generate a URL without the application context being pushed. This has to be executed when application context is available.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i tried so many different things. i updated `pip` for this project's `virtualenvironment` and updated the `pytest` and `pytest-flask`. but none did work.

I was able to pass the tests by:

- removed the `pytest` and `pytest-flask` from `virtualenvironment`.
- removed my system-wide installations of them.
- strangely, i had a package named `flask-pytest` i removed it(in the `env`)
- installed them again system-wide.
- installed them again on `virtualenvironment`.

i don't know how this had anything with the tests, but it worked. the only thing different is that i didn't installed the said `flask-pytest` thing.

Comment: This. The problem is the confusion between flask-pytest and pytest-flask. Pytest-flask is the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

You need to delete your incorrect `client fixture` (see the implementation of `pytest-flask` for the correct one).

Afterwards you need to install `pytest-flask` and `pytest` inside of the `virtualenv`, you better remove the system wide ones to avoid confusion.

Afterwards you should be able to run your tests.

Comment: client fixture was for the second type of testing and implementing. what you say is the first  type of code i have provided, and that didn't work. im still experimenting and may change the solution based on the exact thing i did to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. The solution was:

```
pip uninstall pytest-flask
```